# jQuery.load() with object parameter to Pyramid causes "No JSON object could be decoded"

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, json, pyramid

A simple call like this:

```
type = 'theType';
category = 'theCategory';
$('#mydiv').load(
  '${request.route_url('theUrl')}',
  {type:type, category:category}
);
```

results in a "No JSON object could be decoded" error when I try to access the `request.json_body` object. Looking at the request, I can see that it is a POST, X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest, and that the body is `type=theType&category=theCategory`, which certainly isn't JSON.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Pyramid 1.3, Mako 0.72, jQuery 1.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery.load()` does *not* send JSON. In pyramid, simply access the form variables like you would with a normal POST request:

```
request.params['type']
```

etc.

Comment: Yes, that does explain it. I find it counterintuitive since $.ajax does send JSON data (if you `JSON.stringify` it). Too bad there's no option to tell jQuery how to encode the data. Thanks.